# Using module as variable

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am parsing through some code for an SSD simulator. The top module imports the package `experiment`. It later instantiates an object to this module as follows:

```
from config_helper import experiment
.
.
.
if __name__ == '__main__':
.
.
    experiment = RunFTL(args)
    experiment.run()
```

Inside the `experiment` module, there is an `Experiment` class that has a main function defined. I am just wondering what is happening in the `experiment = RunFTL(args)` operation. I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you want to achieve?

Comment: In the end I need to modify the garbage collection formula, but for now I just need to figure out what the simulator is doing. I am just confused on how python is parsing this assignment operation, as it seems to be instantiating a class into an entire module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just rebinds the name, much like the `x = 2` in

```
x = 1
x = 2
```

Before the assignment, `experiment` in this scope referred to the object imported from `config_helper`. After the assignment, `experiment` in this scope refers to the new instance of `RunFTL`.

Reassigning imported names like this is almost always a bad idea. People expect imported names not to be overridden, plus reassigning a variable to something completely unrelated with its original usage is a bad idea in general.